# How to read information from request data to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm trying to add the model Posts to Blog. Post has blog_id. I need to set it when post create.

```
= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path(blog_id: @blog.id)
```

Here is the button to create new post. In address i see:

> http://localhost:3000/posts/new?blog_id=27

But I dont know how to send this blog_id to post_form. Should I use hidden form or what? Or maybe i need to write something in controller. Bear to me, i'm new at rails. Also, i want to know, is it the right way to set blog_id to post?

upd
_post_form

```
= simple_form_for [@post] do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :content

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: using `hidden_field` in form is a good option than passing post_id in url

Comment: do you want to make a `POST` request with this `link` tag?

Comment: @titan thie link tag redirects you to post form

Comment: @Deepak can you help me with hidden form? check my form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `hidden_field` and access `params[:blog_id]` which you are sending with `new_post_path`

```
= simple_form_for [@post] do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :content
    = f.hidden_field :blog_id, value: params[:blog_id]

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use relations between posts and blog, declare it in the posts model as has_many or has_one relationship so that will give you the chance to access to the object as:

```
@blog = blog.posts.find(:id)
```

i suggest you to follow this part of the tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts it really helped my while doing a project

Comment: if I do @blog = blog.posts.find(:id), i got an error: undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass